# In Kafka, how to locate certain partition according to offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka high level java consumer api. It just uses one single offset to retrieve data from kafka. However, one topic could have multiple partitions. How Kafak locate certain partition according to the offset consumer holds?

Comment: High-level API takes care of the offset management. You only need to specify the topic, and do not have to worry about the offset things.

Comment: Can High-level Api guarantee the overall sequence across all the partitions?

Comment: Kafka only provides a total order over records within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic.